# What conditions cause issues with bacteria in supply pipes other than copper such as PVC or PEX?

Tags: safety, pex, copper-pipe

I know that copper is naturally antibacterial, and that seems like an advantage of running copper pipe.

If PEX is becoming more common, how are problems with bacterial growth inside the pipes being avoided, or is this just a non-issue altogether since things like water mains and wells aren't copper anyway and people are just bringing up bacteria as nothing more than an irrelevant apologetic for copper pipes?

Comment: The antibacterial properties of copper are greatly oversold by the propaganda you've evidently been exposed to. One it's been in place a few months the interior of the pipe is not longer of any use for that purpose, unless you're wire-brushing the inside of the pipe regularly...

Comment: I mean *is it* propaganda?  That's more or less exactly what I am asking with the wording "... nothing more than an irrelevant apologetic for copper ..." in my question.

Comment: Where are you getting your water? Municipal water supplies often contain an antibacterial agent added at the pumping station; It burns off, but since there's no way for bacteria to get back _in_....

Comment: Stagnant/unused water in pipes is the biggest problem.  You go away for few months and the water in your pipes will need treatment and use.  Use two buckets filled with water.  One is just left alone for two weeks.  The other has the water changed everyday, I think you will tell which one is which.

Comment: In my case, it is a well, so I would expect there to be some bacteria in the water supply.  Bad, good, moot?  I don't know.

Comment: @crip659 I am away from home for weeks at a time, so this is a concern.

Comment: Most health departments will test your water for you.  Simple potable water tests can be free, you need to check with the local department.  I imagine you turn off the water, but you can have someone you trust come by every couple of days to turn on the water and run it though the taps.

Comment: If worry or known problem there are UV/anti-bacterial filters that can help, but you will need to do the research if they are good for you.  Testing is the only way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's propaganda.

Have an authoritative site: https://copperalloystewardship.com

Relevant quote, emphasis added by me:

> Laboratory testing shows that, ***when cleaned regularly***, antimicrobial copper surfaces kill greater than 99.9% of the following bacteria within 2 hours of exposure:

You're *not* cleaning the inside of your copper pipes, unless you're as paranoid as Howard Hughes in his dotage, and equipped with a budget of his scale as well.

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation.  I thought it sounded like one of those anti-technology type of arguments, but wanted to see if there was any truth to it.  Looks like not.